# Move between Brackets - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Imagine that I have an huge code, and huge function in the same file. Every function (in almost languages) has an "begin" bracket and an "end" bracket. I would like to know if there is any way (shortcut) to move automatically from "begin" to "end" bracket and vice-versa. I know that exists an highlight, but in a huge code, sometimes, is hard to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> shortcut to move between matching braces